# ExpressJS deleteRoute not updating user data

Tags: javascript, express, controller

I have an express controller to delete user posts which is removing the post from the page, but not from the User.posts data.

```
function deleteRoute(req, res) {
  Post
    .findById(req.params.id)
    .exec()
    .then((post) => {
      if(!post) return res.status(404).send('Not found');

      return post.remove()
      .then((thisUser)=>{
        if (!Array.isArray(thisUser.posts)) {
          thisUser.posts = [];
        }
        thisUser.posts.slice(post.id);
        thisUser.save();
        res.redirect(`/users/${req.user.id}`);
      });

    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).end(err);
    });
}
```

When I create a post, the post count for the user increments, but doesn't decrement when I delete. I think it's probably happening where I'm trying to slice the post.id but i'm not really sure how to fix it. Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Might be helpful: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/
"The $inc operator accepts positive and negative values."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with the following:

```
function deleteRoute(req, res, next) {
  Post
    .findById(req.params.id)
    .then((post) => {
      if(!post) return res.notFound();
      return post.remove();
    })
    .then((post) => {
      console.log(post);
      User
      .findById(req.user.id)
      .then((thisUser)=>{
        const index = thisUser.posts[thisUser.posts.length-1];
        console.log('post deleted:' + index);
        if (index === thisUser.posts[thisUser.posts.length-1]) {
          thisUser.posts.splice(index, 1);
          return thisUser.save();
        }
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.redirect(`/users/${req.user.id}`);
    })
    .then(() => res.status(204).end())
    .catch(next);
}
```